# Javascript works great locally, but not on my server

Tags: javascript, xml, rss

I'm teaching myself javascript by creating a script for displaying an external rss feed on a webpage.

The code I patched together works great locally. This is a screen grab of the code producing exactly the desired behavior. The code is populating all the information inside the section "Blog: Shades of Gray", except for "tagged" which I hard coded:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/fNO5OPnmGPm2]

But when I upload the site files to my server, the code doesn't work at all. This is a screen grab of the code on my site NOT producing the desired behavior...

[image]

This feels like I'm not getting something really basic about how javascript works locally vs. on the server. I did my half hour of googling for an answer and no trails look promising. So I'd really appreciate your help.

This is my site (under construction) http://jonathangcohen.com

Below is the code, which can also be found at http://jonathangcohen.com/grabFeeds.js.

```
/*Javascript for Displaying an External RSS Feed on a Webpage
Wrote some code that’ll grab attributes from an rss feed and assign IDs for displaying on a webpage. The code references my Tumblr blog but it’ll extend to any RSS feed.*/

window.onload = writeRSS;

function writeRSS(){
    writeBlog();
}

function writeBlog(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://blog.jonathangcohen.com/rss.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    //append category to link
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
      {     
      if (i == 0){
          //print category
          var blogTumblrCategory = x[i].getElementsByTagName("category")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
          document.getElementById("getBlogCategory1").innerHTML =  
         '<a class="BlogTitleLinkStyle" href="http://blog.jonathangcohen.com/tagged/'+blogTumblrCategory+'">'+blogTumblrCategory+'</a>';
          //print date
          var k = x[i].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
          thisDate = new Date();
          thisDate = formatTumblrDate(k);
          document.getElementById("getBlogPublishDate1").innerHTML = thisDate;
          //print title
          var blogTumblrTitle = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
          var blogTumblrLink = x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
          document.getElementById("getBlogTitle1").innerHTML =
          '<a class="BlogTitleLinkStyle" href="'+blogTumblrLink+'">'+blogTumblrTitle+'</a>';
          }
     if (i == 1){
        //print category
        var blogTumblrCategory = x[i].getElementsByTagName("category")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        document.getElementById("getBlogCategory2").innerHTML = 
        '<a class="BlogTitleLinkStyle" href="http://blog.jonathangcohen.com/tagged/'+blogTumblrCategory+'">'+blogTumblrCategory+'</a>';
        //print date
        var k = x[i].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        thisDate = new Date();
        thisDate = formatTumblrDate(k);
        document.getElementById("getBlogPublishDate2").innerHTML = thisDate;
        //print title
        var blogTumblrTitle = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        var blogTumblrLink = x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        document.getElementById("getBlogTitle2").innerHTML =
        '<a class="BlogTitleLinkStyle" href="'+blogTumblrLink+'">'+blogTumblrTitle+'</a>';
        }
     if (i == 2){
        //print category
        var blogTumblrCategory = x[i].getElementsByTagName("category")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        document.getElementById("getBlogCategory3").innerHTML = 
        '<a class="BlogTitleLinkStyle" href="http://blog.jonathangcohen.com/tagged/'+blogTumblrCategory+'">'+blogTumblrCategory+'</a>';
        //print date
        var k = x[i].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        thisDate = new Date();
        thisDate = formatTumblrDate(k);
        document.getElementById("getBlogPublishDate3").innerHTML = thisDate;
        //print title
        var blogTumblrTitle = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        var blogTumblrLink = x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        document.getElementById("getBlogTitle3").innerHTML =
        '<a class="BlogTitleLinkStyle" href="'+blogTumblrLink+'">'+blogTumblrTitle+'</a>';
        }
      }
}

function formatTumblrDate(k){
    d = new Date(k);
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    curr_month++;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    printDate = (curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year);
    return printDate;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: There seems to be too much code, for little results. That for(i,3) is complety useless...

Answer (score 4):

You are running into the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), which has [been discussed many times on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=same+origin+policy).

Answer (score 3):

AJAX runs on a same-origin policy, ie, you can only call your own server.

A fix would be making a call to your server which in turn calls the target server.

Here's how (to give you a general picture ;))

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for this diagram. Nothing like a good visual with some arrows!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an XmlHttpRequest to another domain, crossing the security sandbox and going against the same-origin policy, which means the request to blog.jonathangcohen.com/rss.xml fails, and you get nothing out of it.

The only viable solutions are to either use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) or a proxy on your jonathangcohen.com domain, for example a simple php script that would just contain the following would do the trick:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo file_get_contents('http://blog.jonathangcohen.com/rss.xml');
```

Then you request the data from `http://jonathangcohen.com/rss-proxy.php`

Comment: Hey Seladek, thanks so much for your help - I haven't yet cracked this though. This is what I changed: 1) The bstrurl attribute to xmlhttp.open("GET","http://jonathangcohen.com/rss-proxy.php", false); --- 2) I added a file rss-proxy.php to my main folder and included the following script in there: <?php
echo file_get_contents("http://blog.jonathangcohen.com/rss.xml");?> --- I tested this locally and remotely, but it's not working. I'm new to PHP but I checked things out and it appears file_get_contents has the right syntax. Do I need to enable PHP on my server? Any tips? Thank you!!

Comment: Yes of course this implies you need to have php running on the box. It seems to be working fine though, since if you hit the proxy with the browser you get the feed: http://jonathangcohen.com/rss-proxy.php - It appears that the responseXML property is only available if the content type of the request is text/xml though. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a permissions thing. Cross-site scripting and all. The browser is more lenient on local pages (probably) but won't allow you to do this on an actual server. You'll need to grab that data on the server and then feed it to your javascript.

Comment: Hey all, major thanks for all your responses. This is all really interesting. I found this resource about cross-site scripting which goes into the basics some more: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Haven't figured this out yet, but if any of you are even in Boulder, beer's on me.

Comment: Just a small comment on "learning javascript".. Why not try learning one of the libraries, such as jQuery? I too used to hand-code a lot of my javascript at one point, but I haven't looked back after getting into jQuery. Absolutely LOVE the library :)

Comment: Yeah, jQuery looks awesome. Want to understand the basics first though. It's these little surprises like "cross-site scripting" that are frustrating as hell but obviously necessary to develop a solid foundation in how handshaking works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a cross-origin policy thing, which you can read more about here: http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/

In order for javascript on mydomain.com to fetch resources from blog.mydomain.com, blog.mydomain.com will need to send the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mydomain.com`

The only other way to do it that I know of would be to setup a script on blog.mydomain.com, such as blog.mydomain.com/feed.php, that will return a valid JSONP response. In order to use it, you would then, instead of using XMLHttpRequest, create a `<script>` element, and set the source to `http://blog.mydomain.com/feed.php`. The output from `feed.php` should call a javascript function and pass in the actual content of the XML feed, if that makes sense.

edit: The other answers will obviously work as well, and the specific answer about using a proxy script on your site (that reads in and spits out the content of the feed) would be even easier and would only require a URL change in your existing javascript.